# Including links in text message using twilio API

Tags: php, api, url, sms, twilio

How can I include a url in an outgoing text message using twilio API? I tried, but the message was not sent. Is there a specific format? syntax?

**Update**:
Here's the code: (I am using the php api)
Perhaps the problem is with using a variable in the link? or maybe in a different format?

```
$sms = $client->account->sms_messages->create(
    "xxx-xxx-xxxx", 
    $send_to_number, 
    "Hey $var1. words words $var2. via example.com. 
    see: https://graph.facebook.com/$fb_id/picture");
```

The `example.com` link works perfect, so do `$var1` and `$var2`. But when adding the last link which includes a variable (and it is from facebook graph api, but I don't think that matters), then the message is not sent. Is there any way to solve this without url shortener?

Comment: Does sending messages without the URL work? As long as the message content is shorter than 160 characters, there's nothing preventing a URL from being there.

Comment: Can you post code, or the error message you received when you tried to send the message?

Comment: @John Sheehan Yes, it is working just fine without the url, I'll check the length, that might be the issue. Kevin - it is working w/o the url, I don't know whether I should add quotes or anything around the url or not; where should I find the error message? The page is loading, just not sending the message..

Comment: Hi Lucy, Can you paste your code? It would make it easier for us to help you.... Or email it to help@twilio.com.

Comment: The specific error message from Twilio will tell you if the message was too long.  To avoid running into this I'm using google's URL shortener on my URL before creating the message.  I've got a post on this at http://www.princesspolymath.com/princess_polymath/?p=521

Comment: @kirsten - your link has nothing on url shortening

Comment: Actually it does.  Search for urlshortener in the page.  It's not explicitly explained, it's just part of the code I'm using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is too long. 
There is a limit of characters in a twilio message. This has nothing to do with the variable. It now works, just shortened the text.

Answer (score 7):

SMS messages sent via Twilio are limited to 160 characters because carriers will break messages up into 160 character sized chunks.  These chunks doen't necessarily arrive in order, so it is recommended to send some sort of pagination along with the message if you expect it to be over 160 chars.

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms#sms-technical-3

The official Twilio [PHP helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install) will error out if you attempt to send a message longer than 160 characters.

Something else to watch out for: if you break your message into two lines like you have done here, PHP will include the characters you used for indentation in the message, so the above code will produce an SMS message that looks like this:

```
Hey $var1. words words $var2. via example.com. 
                     see: https://graph.facebook.com/$fb_id/picture
```

Comment: I just broke them up to 2 lines so it will look better here in stackverflow. Thanks for your response though! good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio recently updated their api. You can now send messages longer than 140 characters.

Such messages will be automatically split into pieces for each carrier.